# Suppress validation when clicking button in DataGridView column

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to suppress validation when the user clicks a button in a `WinForms` [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.aspx)? I am using [`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn.aspx) for the button column. VB.Net and .Net 4.0.

---

I have a column where the user enters file paths, and a button column next to it. The user can click these buttons to show a common dialog and browse for files, and the file path chosen will be stored back in the first column. In the [`CellValidating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) event I validate that the file path exists. But it's not user-friendly to apply this validation when the user clicks the "browse" button to choose a different file!

For a standalone button I would set [`CausesValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx) to `False`. But I don't want to disable validation for the whole `DataGridView`, just the buttons. I cannot find any suitable property on the [`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn.aspx).

```
Private Sub mDataGridView_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, 
  ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) 
  Handles mDataGridView.CellValidating

  Dim sValue As String = e.FormattedValue.ToString

  If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    If Not IO.File.Exists(sValue) Then
      MsgBox("The file does not exist.")
      e.Cancel = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The community didn't respond at all so I worked harder and found an answer myself on [this MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c693edeb-d76a-47a8-bd78-31b99d502c2f/datagridview-cell-validation-problem)!

```
Private Sub mDataGridView_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, 
  ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) 
  Handles mDataGridView.CellValidating 

  Dim sValue As String = e.FormattedValue.ToString

  If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    'Find current mouse cursor position
    Dim p As Point = mDataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
    Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = mDataGridView.HitTest(p.X, p.Y)
    If (hit.Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell) Then
      'Mouse is over a cell
      If hit.ColumnIndex = <column containing browse button> Then
        If hit.RowIndex = e.RowIndex Then
          'And it's a browse button cell for the same row. Abort validation here.            
          Exit Sub
        End If
      End If
    End If

    If Not IO.File.Exists(sValue) Then
      MsgBox("The file does not exist.")
      e.Cancel = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```